# Use preprocessing function that changes size of input on ImageDataGenerator

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, fft

I wish to take the FFT of the input dataset loaded using ImageDataGenerator. Taking the FFT will double the number of channels as I stack the real and complex parts of the complex output of the FFT together along the channels dimension. The preprocessing_function attribute of the ImageDataGenerator class should output a Numpy tensor with the same shape as the input, so I could not use that.
I tried applying tf.math.fft2d directly on the ImageDataGenerator.flow_from_directory() output, but it is consuming too much RAM - causing the program to crash on Google colab. Another way I tried was to add a custom layer computing the FFT as the first layer of my neural network, but this adds to the training time. So I wish to do it as a pre-processing step.
Could anyone kindly suggest an efficient way to apply a function on ImageDataGenerator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a custom `ImageDataGenerator`, but I have no reason to think this is any faster than using it in the first layer. It seems like a costly operation, since [`tf.signal.fft2d`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/signal/fft2d) takes `complex64` or `complex128` dtypes. So it needs casting, and then casting back because neural network weights are `tf.float32` and other image processing functions don't take `complex` dtype.

```
import tensorflow as tf

labels = ['Cats', 'Dogs', 'Others']

def read_image(file_name):
  image = tf.io.read_file(file_name)
  image = tf.image.decode_jpeg(image, channels=3)
  image = tf.image.convert_image_dtype(image, tf.float32)
  image = tf.image.resize_with_pad(image, target_height=224, target_width=224)
  image = tf.cast(image, tf.complex64)
  image = tf.signal.fft2d(image)
  label = tf.strings.split(file_name, '\\')[-2]
  label = tf.where(tf.equal(label, labels))
  return image, label

ds = tf.data.Dataset.list_files(r'path\to\my\pictures\*\*.jpg')

ds = ds.map(read_image)

next(iter(ds))
```

Comment: Thanks, this is a good option since it can be done as a preprocessing step before training. Could you please tell how I can expand_dims of the tf.data.Dataset.list_files output from (no. of files, height, width) to (no. of files, height, width, 1)?

Comment: It's supposed to return 3 channels, but you can change it in `decode_jpeg`. Or add `image = tf.expand_dims(image, -1)` anywhere